# nmcli hotspot not working when ethernet connected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networkmanager, nmcli

For a home-server I'm using the following nmcli configuration to spawn hotspot and ethernet connections on 192.168.1.50:

```
nmcli con add con-name WIFICON \
    type wifi ifname wlp2s0 mode ap autoconnect yes \
    ip4 192.168.1.50/28 gw4 192.168.1.50 ipv4.method shared \
    ssid MYWIFI \
    wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk MYWIFIPASS

nmcli con add con-name ETHCON \
    type ethernet ifname enp3s0 \
    ip4 192.168.1.50/28 gw4 192.168.1.50 ipv4.method shared
```

Bot work fine individually, but if one device is connected on ETHCON, the WIFICON no longer works.
Can this be achieved? Does it require bonding/bridging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two connections should have different IP addresses if they are to be active at the same time. Then, you might indeed need bridging for example if you want to use the wifi as an AP and offer Internet access to clients by routing traffic through ETHCON (enp3s0).